# Дополнения к рабочему столу

Tags: windows, html, javascript, linux

Как и на чем делают всякие прибабахи на рабочий стол? Слышал, вроде, что ХТМЛ и яваскрипт, но вообще как это все называется и как делается? W7 and Linux.
И можете подсказать по этому вопросу? Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Документация и презентация по разработке гаджетов (все на английском):

- [Windows Sidebar (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965850(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Introducing Windows Vista Sidebar](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DanielMoth/Introducing-Windows-Vista-Sidebar-and-developing-a-gadget)

Answer (score 0):

Да в принципе то на чем хочешь, шарп, делфи и тд.
Создаешь приложение с нужным дизайном и функцией, в реестре прописываешь автозапуск и готово.

Comment: Нет. Автозапуск это вроде как другое. А что бы на рабочем столе были кнопки, панельки другие дребедени, нечто похожее на гаджеты в W7.

Comment: ты читал что я написал? СОЗДАЕШЬ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ с нужными тебе функами(календарь, часы и тд) а далее как написал.

Comment: Насколько я понял, человек интересуется, как сделать гаджет.

Comment: скачайте гаджет с майкрософта, откройте архиватором смотрите и наслаждайтесь

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имели ввиду снег падающий и т.д., то все так же как для сайтов